# Are skill modifiers cumulative (even beyond plus/minus 30%)?

Tags: wfrp-2e, warhammer

I haven't GMed Warhammer FRP 2nd edition for quite a while and my knowledge's gone a bit rusty, I'm afraid.

**Are skill modifiers cumulative (even beyond plus/minus 30%) in WFRP 2nd edition?**

I tried to find the answer in the core book, but all I found was that skill difficulty modifiers are mostly up to the GM, and that they very rarely exceed +/- 30%. Is that correct, or have I missed something?

For example, Hans is about to parry with his off-hand weapon, which gives him a -20% (as it's not defensive and he's not ambidexterous), and it's pouring at night, in a back alley, which I'd say is also a -20% (because it's slippery and dark and Hans can't see much.) Does he roll with -40%, or does it stop at -30% (as all these things make it a "Very Hard" roll which means -30%)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If Hans wanted to attack with off-hand, he'd roll with -40

First of all, accordingly to RAW, you shouldn't assign a penalty for parrying with a secondary weapon. It is a common mistake, because of Ambidexterity's vague description. It is properly explained in the combat chapter. The penalty applies only to attacks from the secondary hand (page 130). Furthermore parrying with a secondary weapon is actually encouraged, as it only takes a free action instead of regular half-action.

Modifiers are cumulative. Multiple modifiers can affect a single test. Most of them provide a bonus or penalty of 10 or 20. Among them, the test's difficulty modifier caps at -30/+30. GMs may assign greater test's difficulty modifier, but ONLY in the case of extremely unusual circumstances. (page 89)

For example:

A group of 3 bandits attacks a single traveler. The first one aims and grapples the traveler. He gains a modifier of +40 (+20 for attacking a foe outnumbered 3 to 1, +10 for aim and +10 for Wrestling talent). The other 2 perform All-Out Attack, gaining +60 modifier in total (+20 for attacking a foe outnumbered 3 to 1, +20 for attacking a grappled foe and +20 for All-Out Attack).

Comment: Thank you. (I'm not entirely sure about the secondary weapon penalty, though, so I think I'll ask a separate question about it.)

Comment: Should you feel interested, here's the new question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143207/20-off-hand-penalty-for-attacks-only-for-other-actions-like-parrying-too